# Where can I find information about Javascript engine internals?

Tags: javascript, documentation, internals

I'm looking for books / articles / papers on Javascript engine internals along the lines of the many reference works about the JVM internals, CLR internals, etc.  I could (and likely will) look at the source code for JavaScriptCore and V8/Chromium, but if there's a book out there or some other "guided tour" documentation, I'd prefer to read them first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the in-depth documents could be the [ECMA-262 Language Specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

A good book on the language's idioms and best practices is [JavaScript The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/)

Answer (score 28):

I was curious about this too, and here's what I found:

About Chrome's Javascript engine (v8):

- [Garbage Collection in V8; For mobile and beyond](http://ajaxian.com/archives/garbage-collection-in-v8-for-mobile-and-beyond)
- [V8 Internals: Building a High Performance JavaScript Engine](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16921039/V8-Internals-Building-a-High-Performance-JavaScript-Engine)
- [Chrome V8 - Design Elements](https://developers.google.com/v8/design?hl=it)

About Firefox Javascript Engine (Spidermonkey):

- [Spidermonkey Internals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Internals)
- [Spidermonkey is on diet](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2011/11/01/spidermonkey-is-on-a-diet/)
- [IonMonkey: Mozilla’s new JavaScript JIT compiler](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/05/ionmonkey)
- [Tracemonkey](http://ejohn.org/blog/tracemonkey/) (obsolete JIT compiler, but however the article is still interesting)

About IE 9+ Javascript Engine (Chakra):

- [Advances in JavaScript Performance in IE10 and Windows 8 -  Internals of Chakra](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/13/advances-in-javascript-performance-in-ie10-and-windows-8.aspx)

About Safari Javascript engine (SquirrelFish):

- [Announcing SquirrelFish](https://www.webkit.org/blog/189/announcing-squirrelfish/)
- [Introducing SquirrelFish Extreme](https://www.webkit.org/blog/214/introducing-squirrelfish-extreme/)

General overview:

- [JavaScript Engines: Under the Hood](http://ontwik.com/javascript/javascript-engines-under-the-hood/)
- [The Future of JavaScript Engines: Replace Them With JavaScript Compilers](http://www.shorestreet.com/node/43)

Answer (score 7):

Google have documented a lot about V8. http://code.google.com/p/v8/  There are some interesting videos on the main page ( although you've probably already seen those )